# How to enable TLS Renegotiation in Tomcat?

Tags: ssl, tomcat6, tls1.2

I want to enable SSL keys renegotiation in Tomcat as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746. Tomcat will use JSSE implementation for SSL. Which cipher suite should I use to enable the same?

- Tomcat Version: 6.0.44
- Java version: Java 1.8
- Protocol - TLS 1.2

Comment: Please close your question http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108192/how-to-enable-tls-renegotiation-in-tomcat6

Comment: FYI - that security stackexchange question is gone, deleted I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta: I'm not sure this is ontopic here, but security is on-hold. Migrate if necessary.

All Java 8 and 7, and 6 from 6u22 up, *enable* secure renegotiation per 5746. [See the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#tlsRenegotiation) By default, it is used if the peer offers or accepts it; if the peer does not, the *connection* is still made but renegotiation is *not* done because it would/could be insecure. This can be varied two ways:

- set system property `sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages` false. JSSE will not make the connection if the peer does not agree to 5746. This is **not actually more secure**, but it is more *visibly* secure to simple minded basic scanners, and people who care about simple minded basic scanners like auditors
- set system property `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation` true. This is **less secure if** the application depends on peer credentials checked after a message. Since client always checks server before any data, this means *if* server requests (not requires) client authentication, and checks auth status after a request, it can wrongly accept a forged-prefix request.

The protocol implementation of 5746 *sometimes* uses a fake "ciphersuite" (officially SCSV -- Signalling Cipher Suite Value) in ClientHello. JSSE *client* can be configured using the "ciphersuite" name `TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV` whether to use this SCSV or the extension. All servers always use the extension, and thus this configuration has no effect on JSSE server.